# Python true global variables (python 3.7.0)

Tags: python, variables, module, scope, global

I know you can use the `global` keyword. But that's not...global. It's just a way to reference another variable outside of this function. If you have one variable that you want to reference it's no big deal I guess (although still troublesome). But what if you have lots of variables that you want to move around functions? Do I have to declare those 2 or 3 or 10 variables each and every time in each function that  are of global scope? Isn't there a way to declare[1] a variable (someplace or somehow) so as to be truly global?

Ideally I would like to have one file *main.py* with my main code and one file *common.py* with all my global variables (declared/initialized[1]) and with a `from common import *` I would be able to use every variable declared in *common.py*.

*I apologize if it's a duplicate. I did search around but I can't seem to find something. Maybe you could do it with classes(?), but I'm trying to avoid using them for this particular program (but if there's no other way I'll take it)*

EDIT: Adding code to show the example of two files not working:

file *main.py*

```
from common import *

def func1():
    x=2
    print('func1', x)

def func2():
    print('fuc2',x)

print('a',x)
func1()
func2()
```

file *common.py*

```
x=3
```

this prints:

```
a 3
func1 2
fuc2 3
```

but it should print:

```
a 3
func1 2
fuc2 2
```

because func2 even though it's called after func1 (where x is assigned a value) sees x as 3. Meaning that fuc1 didn't actually use the "global" variable x but a local variable x different from the "global" one. Correct me If I'm wrong

---

[1] *I know that in python you don't really declare variables, you just initialize them but you get my point*

Comment: Why don't you use a json or yaml-file for that?

Comment: You could gather all of your "truly global" variables in a single dictionary, so only its name would need to be made "truly global" to gain access to all the rest.

Comment: `Ideally I would like to have one file main.py with my main code and one file common.py with all my global variables (declared/initialized[1]) and with a from common import * I would be able to use every variable declared in common.py.` Have you tried this? This is working as expected. What's the problem?

Comment: @Carsten Elaborate pls.

Comment: @Poojan I did, it's not working. You still have to use the global keyword each time

Comment: @Monochromatic I tried its working for me. Can you please show what's not working? Adding little code will help

Comment: @ScottHunter That's actually a good workaround, albeit pretty messy (instead of just using the variable ``x`` you'd have to use it as, say, ``glob_dict['x']``). Still, if I don't find another way I might use this.

Comment: @Poojan added code in question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, every module-level variable is global, and you can mess with them from anywhere. A simple example you might not have realized is `sys`:

```
import sys

myfile = open('path/to/file.txt', 'w')
sys.stdout = myfile
```

`sys.stdout` is a global variable. Many things in various parts of the program - including parts you don't have direct access to - use it, and you'll notice that changing it here will change the behavior of the entire program. If anything, anywhere, uses `print()`, it will output to your file instead of standard output.

You can co-opt this behavior by simply making a `common` sourcefile that's accessible to your entire project:

> `common.py`

```
var1 = 3
var2 = "Hello, World!"
```

---

> `sourcefile1.py`

```
from . import common

print(common.var2)
# "Hello, World!"

common.newVar = [3, 6, 8]
```

---

> `fldr/sourcefile2.py`

```
from .. import common

print(common.var2)
# "Hello, World!"
print(common.newVar)
# [3, 6, 8]
```

As you can see, you can even assign new properties that weren't there in the first place (`common.newVar`).

It might be better practice, however, to simply place a `dict` in `common` and store your various global values in that - pushing a new key to a dict is an easier-to-maintain operation than adding a new attribute to a module.

---

If you use this method, you're going to want to be wary of doing `from .common import *`. This locks you out of ever changing your global variables, because of namespaces - when you assign a new value, you're modifying only your local namespace.

In general, you shouldn't be doing `import *` for this reason, but this is particular symptom of that.

Comment: I can't seem to call ``from . import common``. It returns with *ImportError: cannot import name 'common' from '__ main __' (C:\Users\ [user] \Desktop\d\sourcefile1.py)*. I'm in Python 3.7.0 by the way

Comment: @Monochromatic You can try just `import .common` or even `import common`. Relative imports work in weird ways.

Comment: ``import common`` did the trick and it actually functions the way I want it to. Thanks for the answer and I'll be looking more one the various imports.
Still, I don't get the downvote. Is this a duplicate? All I could find were answers about the ``global`` keyword

Comment: Relative imports only work in directories that contain a file named `__init__.py`.

Comment: This works, but I don't understand why. One can write a very similar program in which Python will create two separate in-memory objects for the `common` module, in which modifying the `common.newVar` from one module will have no effect on the existence of `common.newVar` in the other.